# Correct handling of Python2 and Python3

Tags: bash, python, path, unix-philosophy

What is the correct way running scripts that depend on python2.x but on a system where python3.x is aliased with  python.

The solution should take into account the following things :

- Python2 should be used only for that bash run
- every script that is run form subsequently should also use Python2
- The change should be temporary

One solution is temporary making alias and setting the location for Python2 at the beginning of the full PATH.

What is the right (*nix) way to handle this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way is to use `#!/usr/bin/python2` as shbang line. More and more distributions support this now, and even upstream python development has adopted it.

Comment: yes but if you run a program that afterwards calls `python bla bla ` than this will not work. 
And yes I agree for every new scripts this should be used

Comment: Perhaps `#!/usr/bin/env python2`, since many environments will have `python2`, but not at `/usr/bin`

Comment: The PEP for python2/3 binaries is [PEP 394](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/)